# Can not change outgoing email server

Tags: settings, email

I recently upgraded to android 6 on my Galaxy S6, now I noticed that I cannot send emails from one of my email accounts. It's an imap server, and I need to use another subdomain than the incoming uses for outgoing emails. They are the same now, hence the error, but any changes I attempt are completely and silently ignored.

It seems to accept my changes, but when I go back into the settings again, the same old wrong server settings for outgoing emails glares me right in the face like I've done nothing.

What kind of black magic is this?

Answer (score 0):

I could not resolve this, so I removed the email account and added it again with the correct credentials. Then it worked.